# How to automatically know the name of a field of an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach, cart

I just have a little question, I can't find any answer since I don't know exactly how to formulate it on Google.

So I have this array returned from a query:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [aad3177ec0cbced7a15fae003bdd0ff3] => Array
                (
                    [rowid] => aad3177ec0cbced7a15fae003bdd0ff3
                    [id] => 21
                    [qty] => 1
                    [price] => 176
                    [name] => KRUPS YY1305 
                    [image] => utilities/images/products/p2070396dt.jpg
                    [description] => Menu simplifié pour une convivialité optimale.   
                    [subtotal] => 176
                )
        )
)
```

And I want to get all the information rowid, id, qty ... to store it through a foreach loop in another variable without knowing the name of the second array : 'aad3177ec0cbced7a15fae003bdd0ff3'. I just want to retrieve articles from a cart stored in a database when user logged out.

So how can I say something like :

```
echo $myArray['0'][theNumberGoesHereAutomatically]['price'];
```

Ideally, my code would look like that :

```
foreach ($data2 as $cart){
            $data = array(
                   'rowid'      => $cart_unserialized[$token]['aad3177ec0cbced7a15fae003bdd0ff3']['rowid'],
                   'id'         => $cart_unserialized[$token]['aad3177ec0cbced7a15fae003bdd0ff3']['id'],
                   'qty'        => $cart_unserialized[$token]['aad3177ec0cbced7a15fae003bdd0ff3']['qty'],
                   'price'      => $cart_unserialized[$token]['aad3177ec0cbced7a15fae003bdd0ff3']['price'],
                   'name'       => $cart_unserialized[$token]['aad3177ec0cbced7a15fae003bdd0ff3']['name'],
                   'image'      => $cart_unserialized[$token]['aad3177ec0cbced7a15fae003bdd0ff3']['image'],
                   'description'=> $cart_unserialized[$token]['aad3177ec0cbced7a15fae003bdd0ff3']['description'],
                );
            $this->cart->insert($data2);
            $token++;
        };
```

without knowing the aad3177ec0cbced7a15fae003bdd0ff3.

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try getting the name with `array_keys()`?

Comment: Yes That's it !! Thanks a lot :) (Well yeah, obviously it was easy, but the hardest thing is knowing that this function exist ;p)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this easily with:

```
foreach ($data2 as $varname => $cart){
```

`$varname` will contain `aad3177ec0cbced7a15fae003bdd0ff3`.

Answer (score 2):

```php
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  echo $value['price'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the key with [`key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) function

Answer (score 0):

Use [`current`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) function:

```
foreach ($data2 as $token=>$cartUnserialized){
    $data = current($cartUnserialized);
    // .. proccess your data ..
};
```

Comment: OOoooh yeah, that's the best ! Many Thanks